# Всем привет не работает Pyinstaller Все библиотеки есть всё есть, Pyinstaller переустонавливал раз 20 ничего не помогает. Сам скрипт работает

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Pyinstaller Выдаёт ошибку при попытке конвертировать проект в .exe помогите пожалуйста!
Здесь исходник командной строки не поместился по этому вот ссылка на txt файл. https://drive.google.com/file/d/107x_WR-9z4gWxC1rgcQTbX4x8ZVoF94b/view?usp=sharing
Кто может помогите пожалуйста.